# .pug form not routing properly to Node.js route handler

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a simple form that appears on the home page ('/'). When the form is submitted, the browser is showing correct routing to /search route with several query parameters:

`http://localhost:3000/search?allergens=en%3Aegg&preferences=en%3Avegan&category=breakfast_cereals&excludeTraces=on`

but it is returning 404 error code.

However, when I check the request received by app.js using:

```
app.use('/search', productsRouter);
app.use('/search', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Request to /search:', req.method, req.url);
  next();
});
```

The console prints `/?allergens=en%3Aegg&preferences=en%3Avegan&category=breakfast_cereals&excludeTraces=on`

I'm a novice to relative and absolute routing so I can't tell if the form is appending query parameters to the home page ('/') or if the form is appending a trailing slash that's causing the 404 when /search is called.

Here is the form for reference:

```
extends layout

block content 
  form(name="search", id="search", method="GET", action="/search")
    p Select all allergies in your group:
    select(name="allergens", id="allergens", multiple)
      option(value="en:milk") no milk
      option(value="en:egg") no egg
      option(value="en:fish") no fish
      option(value="en:peanuts") no peanuts
      option(value="en:nuts") no tree nuts
      option(value="en:soybeans") no soybean
      option(value="en:gluten") no gluten
      option(value="en:sesame-seeds") no sesame

    p Select any other dietary restrictions or preferences in your group:
    select(name="preferences", id="preferences", multiple)
      option(value="en:vegan") vegan
      option(value="en:vegetarian") vegetarian
      option(value="en:kosher") kosher
      option(value="en:halal") halal
      option(value="en:organic") organic

    p Enter the product category you're looking for... 
      input(
        type='text'
        name='category'
        placeholder='e.g., breakfast cereals'
      )
    
    p Exclude products with "traces of" allergens in results?
      input(type="checkbox", id="checkboxId", name="excludeTraces")
  
    button(type="submit") search
```

I don't think any middleware is interfering with this route, and I've already ensured that the more specific middleware functions (/search) appear before the more generic ones (/).

Here's what app.js looks like:

```
var productsRouter = require('./routes/api_products');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

...

app.use('/search', productsRouter);
app.use('/search', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Request to /search:', req.method, req.url);
  next();
});
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

in api_products, I have the following route handler, but it's not even getting executed:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET search */
router.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {

    try {

    console.log("call to /search...");
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router in api_products must listen on `/`, not `/search`.
Once it takes control, it has no clue of the original URL. Change in this way:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    try {

    console.log("call to /search...");
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I could imagine only listening for '/' could cause potential confusion if I send other routes (i.e., GET /ingredients) to api_products. Is there anything I can do to make sure routes are properly directed within api_products (other than ordering)? Other options would be to have a separate file for each route or somehow change the URL before it gets sent to api_products.

Comment: It's all up to you... Express has a robust routing system. There's a good tutorial on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes)